# Do Google Maps APIs also accept HTTP POST requests?

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoding-api

I am very new to web development and using any google services api.

I know I can send HTTP GET with the following format:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=CA

I am reading the documentation and it seems that it only talks about HTTP GET requests:
https://developers.google.com/maps/web-services/overview

Does anyone have any experience sending HTTP POST request to google maps apis or it is just not accepted?

Comment: whats your aim sending POST requests ?

Comment: I just want to know if there is a way to send the data encoded.

Answer (score 5):

Based on the Google Maps API documentation https://developers.google.com/maps/web-services/overview you don't have the option to send POST requests but only GET.

Now as your post doesn't provide more infos on how you tried to do it, my suggestion is to create a middleware that will handle those requests.

This is kinda of onverengineering as the parameters will still appear to the user if you are trying to redirect them but it will be a good case if you don't.

You can create a simple `node.js` middleware that will have a `POST` API that you'll send the data the way you want and within this request in the middleware you will transform the data and send them with a GET method to the Gmaps Api.

You can use `Express` to create a middleware without a lot of effort.
You can read more here: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to do things like putting key-value as {"address" : "California"} but since I don't know what is the POST url that I need to hit, I am wondering if it's possible.

Comment: I'm glad I helped. Unfortunately the POST is not an option for gmaps. If you feel it two please up-vote and accept the question. ;)

Comment: surely Google would not force people to expose their API key in a GET request, GET requests get logged in many places and anyone with access to the relevant firewall or server logs, browser history, etc would be able to see your API key in the GET request. This may allow them to then start using your API key and you will be charged for their usage of the API